# a Simple request Ajax jquery symfony 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to get a simple AJAX request to work in Symfony2. It seems that the request is never reaching the controller. Instead of alerting "ajax ok', the AJAX request returns the HTML of the localhost page (wamserver). it is erver Configuration
Apache Version :
2.4.9   - Documentation
PHP Version :
5.5.12   - Documentation
Server Software:
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
Loaded Extensions :
apache2handlerbcmath.............................................

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    { 
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->render(
            'UsuarioBundle:Default:index.html.twig'
        );
    } else {
        return new Response("Ajax ok");
    }
}
```

jquery:

```
 $(function(){
        var data={
                type:'1'                           
    };
        var i = 0;
      $(window).scroll(function(){
       //cuando llegas al final de la página
        if (document.body.scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).height()){
                agregarContenido();
            }
        });
      function agregarContenido(){
            //Agregar el siguiente contenido a mostrar
            var path = "/";
             $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          dataType :'html',
          url:  path,
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
            $('#cuerpo-tabla').append(data);
        },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("error"); // always jump here!! that's the problem!
          }
        });
        }
    });
```

and Routing.yml index:

```
 path:    /
        defaults:  { _controller: UsuarioBundle:Default:index }
```

Comment: What happens if you open `/` directly in your browser?

Comment: Are you sure it is the current page? **dataType** — The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

Try to remove this string:
`dataType :'html',`

Comment: it is page wamserver "localhost"  Server Configuration
Apache Version :
2.4.9   - Documentation
PHP Version :
5.5.12   - Documentation
Server Software:
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12..............

Comment: first of all why you send you request by `POST` method? please look to FOSJsRouting bundle this will help to use route alias instead of `/`. And please post screenshot of message retrieved from ajax. Thanks!